# Why is Foundry VTT healing for 1d8+4?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, healing, foundry-vtt

Skeleton Cloistered Cleric of Urgathoa, Death domain. Everyone in the party has Negative Healing.

In Foundry VTT,

- Single action *Harm 1* is healing 1d8+4.
- Two action *Harm 1* is healing 1d8+12.
- Single action *Harm 2* is healing 2d8+4.
- Two action *Harm 2* is healing 2d8+20.

I can't account for the +4 found in each of these. (This amount is equal to my casting stat mod, but that is perhaps coincidental. I can't check at the moment.)

From the comments: *(edited for readability)*

> - "What level are you?"
>   4; Been adding the +4 since level 1.
> - "Do you have Harming Hands?"
>   No.
> - "Without mods?"
>   There are some QoL mods.
> - "Version?"
>   I'm not sure, and I can't check now. There was a major update recently in Foundry, but we haven't done that upgrade in case of incompatibilities with the Adventure Path components.

Bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Maybe Undeath's Blessing?

Perhaps you took an Undead bloodline [sorcerer dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=11) and basic [bloodline spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=737)? This grants you [Undeath's Blessing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=518). This is achievable at level 4, and would give you a +4 to your Harm spells for healing. I can't find any other way to achieve this, shy of some magic item I'm unaware. It's a very possible and logical level 4 build as a Cloistered Cleric. It's also somewhat possible that someone cast this *on* you, or the target you are healing. Or that someone *was* going to get that ability on their character, added it, toggled it on, and then removed it in favor of a different ability.

I can't *guarantee* that's the answer, as if you've been adding the +4 since level one then I'm plumb out of ideas, but I can say with reasonable certainty in that case that it's one of:

- A bug
- An obscure magic item
- Homebrew

Something involving Undeath's Blessing is still my best guess though - it lines up to perfectly numerically for your level, *and* has equal effects for levels 1 and 2 harm.

Comment: None of that. The lack of something obvious is answer enough: As expected, I shouldn't be getting that +4. Thank you.